Paying cash for a house vs mortgage in current market in risk-averse scenario
A friend states, "Paying cash for a house is the dumbest thing a person could possibly do." Mortgages are currently at about 6.8%. Assume the following:

Money market accounts are earning 4.8%.
Risk-averse scenario (older person), so 4.8% is
probably the maximum possible at the moment
Equity in current home exceeds the cost of the
home to be purchased
Cash from sale of home is not needed for other things---other income and liquid assets available.
12% tax bracket
Person does not itemize deductions

In that scenario, why would someone sell a home, invest the proceeds at 4.8%, and take on a mortgage at 6.8%? Wouldn't getting a mortgage only make sense if the proceeds could earn more than 6.8%?

Note that it doesn't have to be either-or. Always try to pay at least 20% in cash to avoid PMI costs, but outside of that it's really up to you. I could have paid cash but instead financed 50%, keeping that as effectively a leveraged investment, since I was fairly confident I could get returns for exceeding the mortgage interest rate.

Also note that taking out a HELOC loan later is usually more expensive than a mortgage but not much more so, so having equity tied up in the house is not necessarily a problem

@Keshlam Your situation is the opposite of the proposed scenario, "since you were fairly confident you could get returns for exceeding the mortgage interest rate."

If you can't get better returns than the interest you're paying, the leverage option is off the table and it's strictly a matter of how much you are willing to spend vs. how much you need to retain as reserves.

@Keshlam That's what I thought. I would rephrase, for this scenario, as "If you're not willing, for whatever reason,  to make a riskier investment that would earn more than the mortgage rate, then getting a mortgage is off the table." Clearly there are investments that pay more than the current mortgage rate, but that's moot if the individual is unwilling to take on more risk. In this case, the proceeds from the sale of the current  home are not needed for reserves. Do you agree with my rephrasing?

No. There is also opportunity risk due to the delay in tapping a house's equity. Becoming house-rich but cash-poor isn't lowest risk either. Hence my suggestion to consider what balance is comfortable rather than only looking at the extremes. Example: if your jib suddenly moves to another city, having all your wealth tied up in the house is going to make relocating difficult.

I see your point, Keshlam. Thank you.

Your friend is incorrect.  There are many scenarios in which paying cash for a home is a wise choice.  I am going to assume this person is on the young side.  As such it is easy to ignore risks as they have time to recover if things do not go well, and generally speaking there are less assets at risk.
The principles that one tends to use is that over the long haul many index funds have a 10% return.  Then it follows, if you can get a mortgage for significantly less than that then it is wiser to invest and have a mortgage.
The problem, again, is the risk.  When things go down, everything tends to go down.  So bad economic times hit:  Your investments are now worth half of what you invested.  Your either lose your job, or your salary is reduced.  Your home is now worth half of what you paid for.
At that time it would be nice to have a paid for home.  By not having a mortgage your income requirements to stay afloat is greatly reduced.  You can either absorb that pay cut, or work a lower paying job to make ends meet.  Your investments can sit, and wait until the economy recovers.
This is exactly the kind of thing that happened in the period between 2005 and 2008.
There is also a peace that comes with having little or no debt.  For most, their biggest expense is housing with a mortgage or rent taking up the majority of that amount.  What would your life be like if that was removed from your life?
Its wonderful.

I would use 8% rather than 10% as my long-term expected return. If concerned about safety, maybe I'd tweak that lower for planning purposes. But also remember that you may have the opportunity to refinance the mortgage if rates drop; my mortgage started at 6. 5% and was refinanced twice bringing it down to 3.25%

Taking a loan so you can make an investment that earns less than what you pay in interest on the loan is indeed usually a money-losing proportion - you will pay more in interest than you earn from the investment.
There can be tax implications that nudge the break-even point in favor of the loan, since you may get a tax break on the mortgage interest but not the investment income. This also doesn't take into account future behavior of interest rates - it may make sense to take a fixed 6.8% mortgage today to make an investment at 4.8% if you believe the investment rate will rise above the mortgage rate during the life of the loan. Of course, there are also personal and cashflow reasons to get a loan - one would generally prefer to keep some liquid assets rather than having a paid-off home and zero cash. A fixed-rate mortgage is also effectively risk-free as you know exactly the return of each dollar you put into it, while stock market returns can go up or down.
Overall, it's generally better to put your money wherever it has the highest expected return, although there are a number of considerations around tax, cashflow, and expectations for the future that may affect that "expected return" over the life of the mortgage, which aren't captured in the numerical interest rates. It's a little more complicated than just comparing the interest rate numbers, but it's a good starting point.

Additional facets.

refinancing. You have a high mortgage and in the future obtain a lower mortgage
bankruptcy. Chapter 7, walk away from the home.
homestead exemptions. Protection from creditors.


Earning 4.8% in a high interest environment is not risk averse - there's a clear risk of inflation materializing. Even bank deposits now can pay more than that if you look hard enough. So the assumption is unreasonable.
But even with that, there may be reasons to prefer leverage over cash payment depending on the personal situation and the expectation of future performance and market. For example if the rent income covers the interest expense it might make sense.

By "risk adverse" I mean the person cannot afford to lose principal. There is no rent income.

The thing to do is perform the calculations over time. Lots of people want to play this game with interest rates; almost no one ever does the math long-term.
In the current moment, right now, at the time of reading this, your idea makes sense. Does it still make sense in the future if you do it right now. The answer is likely no.
You need to do the math and make a real plan. Asking friends and the internet is not a real plan. You will only ever get their opinions that are not based on the real math.
The process to answer your question is very complex, but I have done these calculations many times, and it almost never works out the way you're thinking it will. It is very rare.

The internet is helplessly addicted to their little games with debt and refuse to admit to the damage they are doing. It is a real addiction.
